# Facebook Login Button Error (WebMatrix)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, razor, webmatrix

Ok, so I'm using the default project found everywhere to show off the Facebook helper. It works great for ME. But nobody else can login. The login window appears and disappears so fast I have no idea what's going on.

http://makemoneyfromyourfacebook.com/

Can anyone give a hand with what might be wrong?

This is the sample that I built up from:  http://john.katsiotis.com/blog/webmatrix---facebook-connect-sample-facebook-helper

I didn't alter ANYTHING in the login/user system. I've only changed the looks.

Comment: Is that an attempt to spread your site's url ?

Comment: Not at all. Try the login button, it don't work. And the site is NO WHERE from being done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue with one of my browsers using the Facebook login helper. It was only happening in google Chrome (not sure what version, because of how they always updates behind the scenes)

It was working fine, then one day it did exactly the same thing as it is doing to you. I cleared all my browser cache and cookies and then it started to work again.